# jQuery unrecognized expression: #

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code works to the point that it removes the class hidden from the hidden object but it refuses to add it back, I've tried different method without success.

Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #

```
$(function() {
  $('img').on('click', function() {
    var me = $(this).attr('class')
    var x = $('#' + me)

    if(x.hasClass('hidden')) {
        x.removeClass('hidden')
    } else {
        x.addClass('hidden')
    }

  });
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BpoMQg?editors=1111

Made a codepen of the work I'm doing, it made me realize the problem however I am still in need of a better way of doing it.

The problem was that I was trying to use the now unhidden image to close it down but since my 'me' variable was searching in classes it fails, however works if you press the same image again.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: two things: `#` is for selecting elements by id. Second: your error means that `me` is the empty string.

Comment: I don't see why you need to use a class to pick another element by id. Whatever you are doing I'm pretty sure there is a better way of doing so.

Comment: Provided more info and made a codepen to briefly explain my work, also realized the problem but it remains unsolved. And yes there probably is a more efficient way of doing it.

Comment: Do you want to switch between two images? E.g. on click - hide current show next?

Comment: I want image one to show image two and image two to hide itself however image 1 stays static, the only one whom switches between visible and not is image two. Click on image one show image two and image one remains unchanged, clock image two hide image two.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean this?

```
$(function() {
    $('img').on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('hidden');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, based on your description, that should be it:

```js
$(function() {
    $('img').on('click', function() {
   if($(this).index()==0) {
  
   $(this).next().toggleClass('hidden');
   }
   else
     $(this).toggleClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

```css
img {
  display:block;
  margin:5px auto;
}
.hidden {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

<img class="1" src="https://images.blogthings.com/thelollipoptest/lollipop-3.jpg" alt="PREVIEW_IMAGE:1">

<img id="1" class="hidden" src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="PREVIEW_IMAGE:1.1">
</div>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was trying to do, thanks! Also cheers for understanding!